# Postgres - does the position of order by matter?

Tags: sql, postgresql, limit, offset

Hi i have a table with entities, the id is generated from a sequence

i have more than 2mio entries in my table and now i want to page through all elements. but

```
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 2000000
```

is too slow for me, so i tried two different statements (pseudocode)

```
int i = 0;    
while(true) {
    a: SELECT * FROM entity WHERE id>=i ORDER BY id LIMIT 100 
    b: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM entity ORDER BY id)a WHERE id>=i  LIMIT 100 
    i=<id of last fetched row>;
}
```

both querys are fast and seem to show the right result... but i have a foreboding that a won't work always... any ideas? And do i need the ordering at all?

Comment: You might explore other paging strategies, like setting fetch size but issuing the entire query at once.

Comment: i'll have a look at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes in your queries position of `order by` **does matter**. AFAIK, In SQL specification, order of rows in resultset is not guaranteed at all if you not specify `order by` in outermost query. Sometimes you can get rows ordered as you want by chance, but there's no guarantee.

To show it, here's the little test - suppose we have table `test` like this:

```
create table test(id int, name text);

insert into test 
select 1, 'John' union all
select 2, 'Adele';
```

Now let's run some queries. This one will work fine (guaranteed by `order by`):

```
select * from test as t1 order by t1.name;

id    name
-----------
2     Adele
1     John
```

This one will work fine **almost certainly**, it's select from ordered subquery and SQL have no reason to reorder it:

```
select * from (select * from test order by name) as t1

id    name
-----------
2     Adele
1     John
```

But suppose we have to use self join in this query. This one, again, will work fine (guaranteed by `order by`):

```
select *
from test as t1
    inner join test as t2 on t2.id = t1.id
order by t1.name;

id    name
-----------
2     Adele
1     John
```

but this one will be reordered because of `merge join`. SQL have to order collections by joined columns during merge join so it reordered `t1`, and since you've not specify outer `order by`, will return results ordered by `id`:

```
select *
from (select * from test order by name) as t1
    inner join test as t2 on t2.id = t1.id;

id    name
-----------
1     John
2     Adele
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7357f/2)</kbd>**

For you original question, even specifying `order by` in outermost query could not work if there're some data modification occured between your selects.

Comment: ok i can assume while looping through pages there will be no inserts/deletes. will query a work? or will i have to use b?

Comment: I think that if you assume that there would be no data modification, then a will work fine